# Как использовать clearInterval в моем случае?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день! Помогите разобраться. 
Необходимо , что функции с анимацией funRotate срабатывала только при наведении на кнопку , если мышь не на кнопке или ушла с нее функция работать не должна.

```
    var i = 0;
    var thesquare = document.getElementById('myID');
    function FunRotate() {
        switch(i) {
            case 0:
            thesquare.style.transform = 'rotate(20deg)';
            i++;
            break;

            default:
            thesquare.style.transform = 'rotate(-20deg)';
            i=0;
            break;
        }

    }

    //var set = setInterval(FunRotate, 500);

    var elem = document.querySelector('.get-report-btn');

    elem.addEventListener('mouseover' , function(){
        var set = setInterval(FunRotate, 500);
    });

   elem.addEventListener('mouseover' , function(){clearInterval(set)}
);
```

Comment: вынеси объявление `set` за `addEventListener` и желательно не называй его set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как написал Алексей Шиманский:

```
var interval;

elem.addEventListener('mouseover' , function(){
    interval = setInterval(FunRotate, 500);
});

elem.addEventListener('mouseover' , function(){clearInterval(interval);} );
```

Comment: Спасибо , работает.